# How to write pojo class as a data model for complex xml structure

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I'm parsing an XML document which has a fairly complex data structure.

Example:

```
<Companies>
    <LISTID>6353HHJDLS628JNHJ6</LISTID>

    <Company>
        <ID>123ABC</ID>
        <Value>True</Value>
        <Order>
            <Text>Because </Text>
            <ListOfReasons>
                <InputName>
                    <Text>your company did not meet requirements</Text>
                </InputName>
                <Text>, </Text>
                <InputName>
                    <Text>your company was not listed as qualified</Text>
                </InputName>
                <Text> etc...</Text>
            </ListOfReasons>
        </Order>
    </Company>

    <Company>
        <ID>123DEF</ID>
        <Value>False</Value>
        <Order>
            <Text>We can't get any more details on </Text>
            <NodeName>
                <Text>neither your company or the entity in question</Text>
            </NodeName>
            <Text> right now.</Text>
        </Order>    
    </Company>

</Companies>
</root>
```

How should I model my pojo class? To me it seems it should have nested or inner classes. I am not sure how this would look like

I know all about JaxB but I don't really know how to use it and unless there is some easy way to implement it, I prefer writing a pojo, because I understand it.

I'm DOM parsing and I'd like to represent it in Java objects. That is the purpose for writing this model. Can anyone give me an example data model class using the XML I've shown. Any help or assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There's a great tool that will get you started [here](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/).

Comment: Havent never seen that tool and it is intresting. This convert automatically XML in all Pojos needed. The last think to do is decorate classes/members with `@XmlRootElement`, `@XmlArrtibute` etc and the passing it to JAXB with `unmarshal`

Comment: @Ken Thanks for the tool. Very nice. So don't use a single class with embedded inner loops? Or all separate classes?

Comment: I would use a separate class for each node that has its own complex structure.  The idea is to have your object model reflect your data model.

Answer (score 1):

In your case there are classes like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Companies {
  private String LISTID;

  private List<Company> companies;

  @XmlElement(name = "company")
  public void setCompany(List<Company> companies) {
  this.companies = companies;
  }

  @XmlElement
  public void setLISTID(String LISTID) {
   this.LISTID = LISTID; 
 }
  /** Others standard POJO Methods */
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Company {
  private String id;
  private String value;
  private List<Order> orders;

  /** Like in the previous example**
}
```

With the tool showed above, your work will only to decorate classes with `@Xml*` annotations.